# Is there an arithmetic proof to the AM GM Inequality for 3 variables?

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

As the question states, I am interested in proving the AM GM inequality in 3 variables, namely: $$\sqrt[3]{xyz}\le \frac{(x+y+z)}{3}$$

Clearly, I expanded everything into the following: [a]
$$ xyz \le \frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3(x^2y + x^2z + y^2x + y^2z + z^2x + z^2y) + 6xyz}{27}$$

I have been given that we know the proof of the AM GM inequality in 2 variables, so I attempted from the base case of the mean between xy and z: [b]
$$  \sqrt{(xy)z} \le \frac {xy + z}{2} $$

Thus: [c]
$$xyz \le \frac {x^2y^2 +2xyz + z^2}{4}$$

If I can prove that the right hand side of c is less than the right hand side of a, I will have completed my proof. 
I conjecture that my proof will look like:
$$xyz \le \frac {x^2y^2 +2xyz + z^2}{4} \le something \le \frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 3(x^2y + x^2z + y^2x + y^2z + z^2x + z^2y) + 6xyz}{27}$$

However, this is proving challenging arithmetically. I know that this is possible with calculus, but I am interested in solving the problem without calculus, and from either a geometric, factorial, or arithmetic perspective. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibe duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678174/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2576966/42969. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2435708/42969.

Comment: The link that Martin R commented gives a very beautiful and elementary solution.

Comment: I do like Martin's proof, and have seen it previously. I was wondering if there was a way to do this directly from proving from the 2 variable case, without doing the 4 variable case, arithmetically. If that is not possible I completely understand, Martin R's link's solution is quite elegant.